# How to add lines between bins in plotly histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, data-visualization, plotly

I have produced a basic plotly histogram in the form of

```
plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "histogram")
```

This produces a nice interactive plot, however I was curious as to whether or not it is possible to add lines to show separation in the bins.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code adds spacing between bars:

```
plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "histogram") %>% layout(bargap=0.1)
```